# pointer to an array in c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

The below program gives me an error in the intialisation `(*a)[5]=((*)[])&v;`.
When I don't type at that line then I'm still getting the error.

```
int main()
{
    int v[10];
    int **p;
    int (*a)[5];
    (*a)[5]=((*)[])&v;
    printf("%d\n",*a);
    printf("%d\n",sizeof(v));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you think you are doing? What is a supposed to be?

Comment: Oh the pain.....

Comment: I want to assign the array v to the pointer to an array a. I'm testing whether the assignment is possible as well as with p.I was reading an article of is array really a pointer. so wanted to test it.

Comment: You know, it's bad enough that correct dereferencing syntax often looks like gibberish already. It didn't need additional help.

Comment: A judicious typedef or two might be a good idea.

Comment: a is a pointer to an array its an array of pointers ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you mean error, you probably refer to run-time error. int (*a)[5] is a pointer to an array of 5 ints, which is never initialized. However on the next line you try to dereference it. You should initialize 'a' before using it, you may be trying to initialize it with v but that's not an array of 5 ints. If you were to redeclare v as int v[5] then a = &v should work.

Comment: While perhaps not the best style, if he uses `(int (*)[5])&v` it ought to work regardless of the size of `v`.

Answer (score 5):

`&v` is a reference to the int array `v`, so it is of type `int **` (essentially). `int (*a)[5]` means you're declaring a pointer to an array of 5 ints. BUT, in the next line, when you write, `(*a)[5]`, it means you are dereferencing `a` to get an int pointer, and then dereferncing again to access the element stored at `[5]`. but arrays in C are zero indexed, so you can only access `[0]` to `[4]`, and `[5]` is not allocated.

You want `a = &v`. This will make `a` a pointer to the int pointer `v`. There are other issues like `*a` is an int pointer so `"%d"` won't fly, you haven't given any values to `a` or `v`, `((*)[])` is just unnecessary, etc.

Comment: To whoever -1'd, could you please comment as to why? I don't think I wrote anything wrong.

Comment: :Thanks for explaining clearly.But &v will give a pointer to an int array and not pointer to pointer to an int. and if tried p=&v; compiler will throw an error stating that  cannot convert from 'int (*)[10]' to 'int **' .

Comment: I didn't -1 but your answer seems to say at several points that arrays are pointers, which is quite wrong. `&v` is of type `int (*)[10]`, not `int **`, and I'm surprised that assignment from a variable of type `int (*)[10]` and another of type `int (*)[5]` works without a cast.

Answer (score 4):

Assignment to variable `a` should only have `a` on the LHS.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is simpler than you are expecting

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int v[10];
    int **p;
    int *a[5];

    v[0] = 1234;
    a[0] = v;

    printf("%d\n", *a[0]);
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(v));

    return 0;
}
```

*a[5] is an array of int * pointers. v[10] is effectively also a pointer to an int.

So *a and a[0] are effectively the same thing.

ETA:    Perhaps printf("%d\n", a[0][0]); is better